# $\sum q^n\sin(nx)$ complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to solve this one?
$$\sum_{k=1}^n q^k \sin(kx) = S(q,n)$$ where $n$ is natural number and $q$ is a real number

I already got the formula $$S(q,n) = \Im\left(\frac{q\exp(ix)(1-q^n\exp(nix))}{1-q\exp(ix)}\right)$$
but I don't know how to simplify the $1-q\exp(ix)$ using the formulas 
$$ \sin(φ)=\frac{\exp(iφ)-\exp(-iφ)}{2i}$$
$$ \cos(φ)=\frac{\exp(iφ)+\exp(-iφ)}{2}\,.$$

Comment: $e^{ix}=\cos\, x+i\sin\, x$. Hyperbolic functions are not involved.

Comment: @SergeiVolkov: You have assumed $|qe^{ix}|<1$, but why?

Comment: Hm... I don't understand why you have the factor of $q e^{ix}$ in the numerator of $S_n$. The summation starts from 0 so the first term is equal to 1

Comment: @MikalaiParshutsich: The first term is $0$ since $\sin kx$ is $0$ when $k=0$ and has rewritten the summation $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n q^k \sin(kx)=\:\text{Imaginary part}\:\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n q^k e^{ikx}\right)$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran... Oh yeah! My mistake =(

Answer (score 1):

Let me recast your formula using $n-1$ instead of $n$, for convenience. First, we reduce the calculation to the sum of a  geometric progression 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \sin(kx) = \Im \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(q\, e^{ix})^k
 = \Im \frac{1-(q\, e^{ix})^{n}}{1-q\, e^{ix}}\,,$$
where we have used
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} s^k  = \frac{1-s^n}{1-s}
$$
(this is easily proved for $s\neq 1$ multiplying both sides by $1-s$ and noting the telescopic sum on the left-hand side; for $s\to1$, the right-hand side reduces to $n$).
Now,
$$
\frac{1-(q\, e^{ix})^{n}}{1-q\, e^{ix}} =\frac{1-q^n\cos(nx)-iq^n\sin(nx)}{1-q\cos x -iq \sin x}=(1-q\cos x+i q \sin x)\frac{1-q^n\cos(nx)-iq^n\sin(nx)}{(1-q\cos x)^2 + (q \sin x)^2}\,,
$$
whose imaginary part is
$$
\frac{q\sin x(1-q^n\cos(nx))-q^n \sin(nx) (1-q\cos x)}{(1-q\cos x)^2+(q \sin x)^2}\,.
$$
Simplifying slightly, by means of trigonometric formulas,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \sin(kx) = \frac{q\sin x - q^n \sin(nx)+q^{n+1}\sin((n-1)x)}{1-2q\cos x+q^2}\,.
$$

Comment: thank you a lot

Comment: Hi @SergeiVolkov welcome to Stack Exchange. In case you find that an answer indeed fits the question you have asked, it is customary to accept it by clicking on the "tick" symbol on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have this solution for the problem:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} q^k \sin(kx) = \Im \sum_{k1}^{n}(q\, e^{ix})^k
 = \Im \frac{1-(q\, e^{ix})^{n}}{1-q\, e^{ix}}q\, e^{ix} \,,
$$
as a geometric series (I don't know why $|q\, e^{ix}|<1$ as you said).

Then, 
$$
\frac{1-(q\, e^{ix})^{n}}{1-q\, e^{ix}}q\, e^{ix} =\frac{1-q^n\cos(nx)-iq^n\sin(nx)}{1-q\cos x -iq \sin x}q\, e^{ix}=(1-q\cos x+i q \sin x)\frac{1-q^n\cos(nx)-iq^n\sin(nx)}{(1-q\cos x)^2 + (q \sin x)^2}q\, (cosx+isinx)\,,
$$
and 
then simplifying the last expressions just by opening the brackets and then using the formula for the $\sin$ of the sum we get 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} q^k \sin(kx) = q\frac{q^{n+1}\sin(nx)-q^{n}\sin((n+1)x)+\sin x}{q^2-2q\cos x+1}\, . 
$$
Sorry, I firstly haven't caught that in the sum k is going not from the 0 but from 1, that is my mistake.

Comment: Even if you let the sum start from $k=1$ instead of $k=0$, what you are doing is nothing but subtracting 1 (a real number) and hence you do not alter the imaginary part and the result (if you will, the imaginary part of 1 is 0). Secondly, at no point there is an assumption on the absolute value of $q e^{ix}$, since you are considering a finite sum! The formula $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a^j=(1-a^{n})/(1-a)$ is valid for any $a\neq 1$ and the sum just gives $n$ as $a\to1$.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I'll try to understand this thing